# Doctrine Uni-Directional ManyToOne and Cascades

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have the following setup

- Todos have Notes
- Notes are authored by Users

.

```
class Todo {
    protected $notes;
}

class Note {
    protected $todo;
    protected $author;
}

class User {
    // does not have any link to Note. 
}
```

User does not have any link to Note, how do I then cascade my persist there. I thought Note being the owning side of the relationship, I just need `$note->author = $user`. And won't need something like `$user->getNotes()->add($author)`. I was thinking if in my app, if I don't need to access Notes from Users, I don't add a link to clutter my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get this right, but; if your User doesn't have a reference to their notes then you won't need to cascade any actions because it's a uni-directional relationship.

Be sure to re-read [Working with Associations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-associations.html).